# Does Solspace’s Tag add-on not allow for tags with ampersands?

Tags: add-on, solspace, solspace-tag

My company’s name has an ampersand in it, so you can imagine it appears quite frequently in tags. The tag displays correctly on the page, but clicking it always leads you to a page with no results. There should be some `urlencode` going on in the plugin to allow for things like this.

Is my only option to modify the Tag add-on myself to `urlencode` links and `urldecode` on the results page?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the {websafe_tag} param to create your links? http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/tags/#websafe_tag

Comment: I sure am. `<li><a href="{path='blog/tag'}/{websafe_tag}" title="{tag}">{tag}</a></li>`

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a tag containing an ampersand. {websafe_tag} works fine to pull entries using {exp:tag:entries}. What version of Tag and EE are you using? You might also want to check your EE allowed characters and .htaccess settings.

Comment: My `permitted_uri_chars` are set to default (`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\\-';`). I tried adding an ampersand but it didn't help. EE version is 2.6.1, and Tag version is 4.2.3.

Comment: Think we'll have to dig in. Please contact us from solspace.com with CP and FTP credentials, and we'll have a look. Please mention this thread as well if possible. Thanks :)

Comment: Was there a solution found for this issue?